# What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?

Tags: books, big-list

Which books/papers should we all have in our shelves?

There are a couple that I use regularly such as:

- [An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation: Mathematics, Stochastics and Computation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Financial-Option-Valuation-Mathematics/dp/0521547571)
- [Asset Pricing (Cochrane)](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/teaching/asset_pricing.htm)

Which ones do you recommend for which topics?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the canonical books for statistics applied to finance?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/15611/what-are-the-canonical-books-for-statistics-applied-to-finance) and [Best written quantitative finance papers](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17163/best-written-quantitative-finance-papers)

Comment: That question is very tailored: "statistics applied to finance" . 
I guess my question is broader. Some examples of answers from the question you mention could be potential answers here. But I am also looking for good references in many other areas: asset pricing, stochastic calculus, econometrics, optimization ...

Comment: No very far from this: 
https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online

Comment: I definitely see some value in this, maybe the ‘best’ part should be removed and just ask for a list.

Comment: Quantitative finance can refer to many different areas such as quantitative trading, financial derivative pricing, and quantitative risk management. You may need to be more specific.

Comment: Maybe we can follow this model: [What data sources are available online?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/141/what-data-sources-are-available-online), including categories such as "Derivatives Pricing", "Quantitative Trading", "Quantitative Asset Management", etc.

Comment: Although it can get messy indeed. I for one have never heard of [An Introduction to Financial Option Valuation: Mathematics, Stochastics and Computation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Financial-Option-Valuation-Mathematics/dp/0521547571).

Comment: I retracted my close vote

Comment: What are the other resources that are similar to Cochrane's asset pricing classes? More precisely, what are the online resources that have online classes, quiz,homework and examination?

Answer (score 93):

## General Finance Textbooks

- *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives*, John Hull
- *The Concepts and Practice of Mathematical Finance*, Mark Joshi
- *Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance*, Paul Wilmott

---

## Asset Pricing

- *Asset Pricing (Revised Edition)*, Cochrane, John H. Princeton University Press, 2009.
- *Financial Decisions and Markets: A Course in Asset Pricing*, Campbell, John Y. Princeton University Press, 2017.
- *Asset pricing and portfolio choice theory*, Back, Kerry. Oxford University Press, 2010.
- *Damodaran on Valuation*, Damodaran, Aswath, Wiley Finance, 2006
- *Dynamic Asset Pricing Theory (Third Edition)*, Duffie, Darrell. Princeton University Press, 2001.

---

## Asset Allocation

- *Introduction to Risk Parity and Budgeting*, Roncalli, Thierry, 2013
- *Asset Management: A Systematic Approach to Factor Investing*, Ang, Andrew, Financial Management Association, 2014
- *Expected Returns: An Investor's Guide to Harvesting Market Rewards*, Illmanen, Anti, The Wiley Finance Series, 2011

---

## Option Pricing Theory and Stochastic Calculus

- *Financial Calculus: An Introduction to Derivative Pricing*, Martin Baxter and Andrew Rennie
- *Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time*, Tomas Björk
- *Stochastic Calculus for Finance I: The Binomial Asset Pricing Model*, Steven Shreve
- *Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models*, Steven Shreve
- *Martingale Methods in Financial Modelling*, Marek Musiela and Marek Rutkowski
- *Mathematical Methods for Financial Markets*, Monique Jeanblanc, Marc Yor, and Marc Chesney
- *Financial Modelling With Jump Processes*, Rama Cont and Peter Tankov
- *Option Volatility and Pricing*, Sheldon Natenberg

---

## Asset Classes

**Equity Derivatives:**

- *Equity derivatives*, Marcus Overhaus et al.
- *Equity Hybrid Derivatives*, Marcus Overhaus et al.
- *The Volatility Surface*, Jim Gatheral
- *Stochastic Volatility Modeling*, Lorenzo Bergomi
- *Dynamic Hedging: Managing Vanilla and Exotic Options*, Nassim Nicholas Taleb
- *Option Volatility & Pricing*, Sheldon Natenberg
- *Option Valuation Under Stochastic Volatility: With Mathematica Code*, Alan L. Lewis

**FX Derivatives:**

- *Foreign Exchange Option Pricing*, Iain J. Clark
- *FX Options and Smile Risk*, Antonio Castagna
- *FX Options and Structured Products*, Uwe Wystup

**Commodity Derivatives:**

- *Commodity Option Pricing*, Iain J. Clark
- *Commodities and Commodity Derivatives*, Helyette Geman
- *Energy and Power Risk Management: New Developments in Modeling, Pricing, and Hedging*, Alexander Eydeland, Krzysztof Wolyniec

**Interest Rate Derivatives:**

- *Interest Rate Option Models*, Rebonato
- *Interest Rate Models – Theory and Practice (with Smile, Inflation and Credit)*, Damiano Brigo and Fabio Mercurio
- *Interest Rate Modeling I, II & III*, Leif B. G. Andersen and Vladimir V. Piterbarg
- *Pricing and Trading Interest Rate Derivatives*, J H M Darbyshire

**Inflation Derivatives:**

- *Interest Rate Models – Theory and Practice (with Smile, Inflation and Credit)*, Damiano Brigo and Fabio Mercurio

**Credit Derivatives:**

- *Credit Risk - Modeling, Valuation & Hedging*, Tomasz R. Bielecki and Marek Rutkowski
- *Modelling Single-name and Multi-name Credit Derivatives*, Dominic O’Kane
- *Interest Rate Models – Theory and Practice (with Smile, Inflation and Credit)*, Damiano Brigo and Fabio Mercurio

**XVA:**

- *XVA: Credit, Funding and Capital Valuation Adjustments*, Andrew Green
- *Counterparty Credit Risk, Collateral and Funding*, Damiano Brigo, Massimo Morini, and Andrea Pallavicini

---

## Quantitative Risk Management

- *Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and Tools*, Alexander J. McNeil, Rudiger Frey, and Paul Embrechts

---

## Mathematics

**Probability and Stochastic Processes:**

- *Probability*, A.N. Shiryaev
- *Probability*, Leo Breiman
- *Stochastic Calculus and Applications*, Samuel N. Cohen and Robert J. Elliott
- *Stochastic Differential Equations*, Bernt Oksendal
- *Diffusions Markov Processes and Martingales*, L. C. G. Roger and D. Williams

**Statistics:**

- *Statistical Inference*, George Casella and Roger Berger
- *Theoretical Statistics - Topics for a Core Course*, Robert W. Keener
- *Time Series Analysis*, James Hamilton
- *The econometrics of financial markets*, Campbell, John Y., Andrew Wen-Chuan Lo, and Archie Craig MacKinlay. Vol. 2. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press, 1997.
- *The Elements of Statistical Learning*, Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman
- *Handbook of Markov Chain Monte Carlo*, Brooks, Steve, Gelman, Andrew, Jones, Galin , and Meng, Xiao-Li.
- *Analysis of Financial Time Series*, Ruey S. Tsay

**Machine Learning**:

- *Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective*, Kevin P Murphy
- *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, Christopher Bishop
- *Reinforcement Learning: An introduction*, Richard S. Sutton and Andrew G. Barto
- *Advances in Financial Machine Learning*, Marcos Lopez de Prado

---

## Programming

- *C++ Design Patterns and Derivatives Pricing*, Mark Joshi
- *Python for Data Analysis*, Wes McKinney
- *Applied Computational Economics and Finance*, Mario J. Miranda and Paul L. Fackler
- *Modern Computational Finance*, Antoine Savine

---

## Interviews

- *Quant Job Interview Questions and Answers*, Mark Joshi
- *Heard on the Street: Quantitative Questions from Wall Street Job Interviews*,  Timothy Crack
- *150 Most Frequently Asked Questions on Quant Interviews*, Dan Stefanica, Radoš Radoičić, and Tai-ho Wang
- *An Interview primer for quantitative finance*, Dirk Bester

---

## Being a Quant

- *My Life as a Quant: Reflections on Physics and Finance*, Emanuel Derman
- *The Quants: How a New Breed of Math Whizzes Conquered Wall Street and Nearly Destroyed It*, Scott Patterson
- *A Man for All Markets: From Las Vegas to Wall Street, How I Beat the Dealer and the Market*, Edward Thorpe
- *The Man Who Solved the Market: How Jim Simons Launched the Quant Revolution*, Gregory Zuckerman

---

## Cultural Classics

- *Reminiscences of a Stock Operator*, Jesse Livermore
- *Liar’s Poker*, Michael Lewis
- *Against the Gods*, Peter Bernstein

Comment: Many titles are missing here and I must admit I haven't read them all but it's a start, please feel free to edit.

Comment: I added a few more.

Comment: Also added a few more. I might make a more detailed (handbook/paper based edit with seminal papers).

Comment: The papers one should probably be a different question entirely. @phdstudent Can you ask that one too, I can make it CW then.

Comment: 1) Some section reorganization for more clarity; 2) some format editing; 3) Added Inflation Derivatives; 4) Included Brigo & Mercurio's also in Inflation and Credit as they provide good overview of topic.

Comment: On another note, personally I am not sure whether probability and statistics books should be included, the sources there are much more diverse IMHO and we could end up with too many references.

Comment: I think the math part should be included, but limited.

Comment: @Bob, I agree with keeping them separate: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38886/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-papers-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves

Comment: I have added Alan Lewis' book, which I feel is excellent but undervalued, to the list for Equity Derivatives

Comment: for clarity, I added Natenberg (something of an options bible) and Wilmott's texts to the list.

Comment: Hands on Machine Learning for Algorithmic Trading by Stefan Jansen

Comment: A great list, but "The Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani and Friedman should be under machine learning, not statistics, or perhaps under both.

Comment: Added the Duffie, in particular for its rigorous treatment of dividends and a neat construction of future prices.

Answer (score 8):

For equities specifically:

*Quantitative Equity Portfolio Management: Modern Techniques and Applications*, Qian, Hua, Sorensen

*Active Portfolio Management*, Grinold and Kahn

Answer (score 7):

« Stochastic differential equations » by Oksendal is my best reference on SDE for practionners who want a rigorous statement of all important results in the topic while maintaining a decent size for the book. In addition it comes with solved exercises so this is a must.

Answer (score 4):

**Simon Benninga** (2014) "*Financial Modelling*" Fourth edition - The MIT Press

Highly recommended!