# Garch models - are they useful for hedging? If so how?

Tags: volatility, hedging, garch, prediction

I understand that Garch models are useful to predict volatility. But are they useful for hedging in practice? If I want to hedge volatility, why shouldn't I just use a Variance Swap?

In other words, other than forecasting volatility, what is the use of Garch type models?

Comment: What makes you think there is or should be another use for GARCH-like models?  They would be as useful for hedging vol as BS would be for hedging option positions (ie, not very as they're both imperfect models)

Comment: Are you looking for [GARCH based option pricing models](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/51408/42766) to hedge your positions?