# Books on banking by Moorad Choudry

Tags: books, banking

What do you think about books on banking written by Moorad Choudhry?

Someone recently recommended them to me as a good general introduction to modern banking, for example:

*An Introduction to Banking: Liquidity Risk and Asset-Liability Management* 
by Moorad Choudhry, 2011

It is not included in [What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves) which tends to cover more specialised areas and does not have a "bank management from a quant perspective" type of book. Have you read his books? Do you think it should be included in our recommended list?

Comment: A long time ago I read his "the futures bond basis" and it was horrendous. So bad in fact that I vowed never to read another book by Moorad Choudhry again. Now, he may have gotten better at writing and he might be more knowledgeable in that field, so I don't want to criticise something unfairly that I have not read. But I would definitely be skeptical at the outset.