# Starting Point for understanding Financial Theory for a Statistician

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, reference-request, statistical-finance, theory

I am a Master’s student in Statistics who is interested in the field of Financial Modelling. I have very little experience or knowledge  of Finance and have mostly worked on introductory projects in finance using CAPM and Event Study Methodology

I am interested in a quick introduction to financial theory which can help me in working with Financial Models. Any suggestions for a good book will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the quantitative finance books that we should all have in our shelves?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Brooks - *Introductory Econometrics for Finance*](https://www.cambridge.org/highereducation/books/introductory-econometrics-for-finance/75E9C608EA95A3AD87FB3BC683B9EBBF) is a very comprehensive, accessible overview of all the mainstream models for capturing non-normality, serial correlation, non-stationarity and other properties of financial returns, data, and volatility, bundled with plenty of reproducible examples.

[Mills and Markellos - *The Econometric Modelling of Financial Time Series*](https://books.google.ch/books/about/The_Econometric_Modelling_of_Financial_T.html?id=nV93bk3mhNoC&redir_esc=y) is another accessibly technical financial econometrics textbook. A good continuation of the first as it moves into the territory of foreign exchange assets and commodities.

Comment: I am going through the first one now and finding it to be very helpful ! Thank you for suggesting these books.

Answer (score 3):

Other than the books described by @develarist, there are also some alternative considerations which I have grouped into overall subjects:

**Financial econometrics/Financial modelling:**

- *Analysis of Financial Time-Series by Ruey S. Tsay*. The book gives you a comprehensive introduction to econometric modelling of financial time-series, including stylized facts of financial time-series, linear time-series modelling, volatility modelling, risk-management, high frequency econometrics and much more. Moreover, The author provide R code in the book, to further help your understanding on the implementation of the models.  [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470414359).
- *Econometrics of Financial Markets by John Y. Campbell et al*. This textbook is also a very good source for financial modelling. It also contains information about Event-Study analysis, CAPM, multifactor pricing models and much more. Personally, I have not used this book in any academical courses, but my supervisor recommended it to me as a good source of information. [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691043019).
- *Financial Modeling Under Non-Gaussian Distributions by Eric Jondeau, Michael Rockinger and Ser-Huang Poon*. This is another good alternative for financial modelling of asset returns. From personal experience, I believe that the book has a more in-depth view of volatility modelling for portfolio construction and risk-management than Ruey's book.  [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1846284198).

If you want to get an understanding of **quantitative risk-management** for a future project, you can always look at:

- *Quantitative Risk Management: Concepts, Techniques and tools - Revised edition by Alexander J. McNeil, Rüdiger Frey an Paul Embrechts.* I believe this is a widely used textbook for quantitative risk-management courses issued by various universities around the world. [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691166277).

If you have knowledge within **machine learning**, you can also look at the book:

- *Advances in Financial Machine Learning by Marcos Lopez de Prado*.     [Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119482089)

Hopefully, this will get you started.

Comment: I am still learning ML but will definitely check out the last book once  I have had enough practice. Thanks!