# What are some good books to get started with option theory?

Tags: options, option-pricing, american-options, option-strategies

Recently graduated in econometrics but starting to realize my knowledge is limited. Any and all tips are welcome!

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves