First Post | Resources to learn Algo Trading/ Quant Development
I have been working as a full stack dev for the past 3 years and I am looking to learn Algo Trading and Quant Dev. Can someone help me with the resources, books, articles and what tech/languages should I learn?
I currently know MERN Stack a little bit of JAVA and a good amount of Python.
Looking forward to connecting with the community and like-minded people.
Thanks in advance!

If you know the job or type of firm you want to apply to, you can check out their job descriptions which may often be informative as to what programming languages they use. As for books for Quantitative Finance, check out;  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves.
