Book Recommendations
I'm a PhD student in theoretical particle physics, and I've recently developed an interest in finance. I've read books on value investing by Benjamin Graham and Peter Lynch, but I'm now eager to explore quantitative finance. Currently, I have no background in stochastic calculus, but I’ve started reading Physics and Finance by Volker Ziemann.
I’d love recommendations for additional resources—books, blogs, online courses, or anything else that covers quantitative finance and includes machine learning and deep learning techniques. I prefer resources that involve Python for coding. Thank you!
PS: I am mostly interested in equity trading and investment in equities.

https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862/what-are-the-quantitative-finance-books-that-we-should-all-have-in-our-shelves

I have already looked at the list but it becomes confusing very fast for someone new on what to pick. Is there any book that gives an introduction to the field for a novice.

General Finance Textbooks in the answer is the best for an introduction to the field.

Quant Finance is divided into Derivatives and Quant Investing. If you are interested in investing (rather than derivatives) take a look at a book in the Asset Allocation section after you read one from General Finance.
