Measuring and managing Credit risk
I am looking for some good text books with SAS/R/Python hands-on examples on Credit risk measurement and management for Retail portfolio as well as broad regulatory expectations. Could you please refer some good textbooks on this field?

Not quite my area, but I can recommend two books that I found helpful when I needed to gain some basic understanding.  Naeem Siddiqi. Intelligent Credit Scoring: Building and Implementing Better Credit Risk Scorecards. Wiley, Second Edition, 2017.    Steven Finlay. The Management of Consumer Credit: Theory and Practice. Palgrave Macmillan, Second Edition,  2010. Regarding the regulatory expectations, are you asking about the U.S.? That varies a lot in different countries.

@DimitriVulis Thanks for the references. Yes, I am mostly focused on US regulatory aspects (from modelling and reporting pov) for Retail credit risk

I should also mention the older Lyn Thomas. Consumer Credit Models: Pricing, Profit and Portfolios (2009). Raymond Anderson. Credit Intelligence & Modelling (2022). Lyn Thomas, Jonathan Crook, David Edelman. Credit Scoring and Its Applications - 2nd edition (2017). Also: not a math book, but helped me "grok" credit: David Graeber. Debt: The First 5,000 Years, Updated and Expanded (2014). For U.S. fair lending, start with https://occ.gov/publications-and-resources/publications/comptrollers-handbook/files/fair-lending/pub-ch-fair-lending.pdf

Do you mind updating the community wiki https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/38862 please.

@DimitriVulis Thanks for your inputs. I have updated the community wiki with this information (link: https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/81322/67741)

Thank you very much @DanielLobo!
